# concat binary files in one omitting the trailer with powershell

Tags: powershell, concatenation, bin

I have several binary files that need to concat to create one, each has the trailer, but it should be omitted, but the result file should include one line trailer. I was trying to do it by creating the hash table and splitting each line in the array by 256 bytes, but do not know how to split it by number of bytes. This is a sample code I am trying to use, but open to other more efficient solutions:

```
$ht=@{}
    filter Get-Record { if ($ht[$_] -ne $TrailerLine) {$ht[$_]} }
    $TrailerLine = $null


    get-content -path $Path\*.* -encoding byte |
    foreach { 
           if (-not $TrailerLine) 
             { $TrailerLine = $_ }

            $counter++
            $ht["$($_.split(???)"] = $_

         }
```

Comment: So, just to make sure I am understanding this correctly, you want the files put together minus the last 256 characters, except that the end result should have the last 256 characters?

Answer (score 2):

The `Get-Content` command has a `TotalCount` parameter that you can use to get all but the last 256 bytes and a `Tail` parameter where you can get the last 256 bytes e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path | 
    Foreach {$last=$_; Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding Byte -TotalCount ($_.Length - 256)} `
            -End {Get-Content $last.FullName -Tail 256 -Encoding Byte} | 
    Set-Content $newFile -Encoding Byte
```

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was going, I just wanted to make sure I understood the question correctly. I always forget that ForEach-Object can be broken down to begin/process/end though, so my answer wouldn't have been as clean as yours. I've learned so much reading your answers since I found SO in Feb I sometimes feel like I should owe you tuition.

Comment: Never even knew you could do `-End`. Is that covered in one of the `about_`'s

Comment: @Matt The `Begin` and `End` parameters on `Foreach-Object` are documented in the man page for the command.  But it is such a simple command that most folks don't bother with the help on it.  ;-)   @TheMadTechnician - thanks, it's good to hear that some of my answers on SO have been helpful.

Comment: Keith. Is there way to count the number of lines on each file or at least the total number of lines processed by this script as I loop through all files? I can surely do the line count when the new file is written, but it is kind of doing it twice. Would be nice to have stats as I went along. Thanks.

Comment: If the files are binary, then does a "line count" make sense? I guess you could increment a variable for every byte equal to 10 (LF).  That is you could stick in another Foreach just before the Set-Content pipeline stage e.g. `... | foreach {$cnt=0} {if ($_ -eq 10) {$cnt += 1}; $_} | Set-Content ...`

Comment: I actually did in two steps, but you are right in regards of line count, it was more about number of bytes. But now I have another hurdle. Your script works fine (from sept 19), if the file length is >0, if one of the files or all of them have length -eq to zero, then it works, but my totals do not match. IS there way to check inside foreach loop if the file read is actually > 0 ?

Comment: Sure, just check `$_.Length -gt 0`. In fact, if you want to skip zero length files, stick in this between the Get-ChildItem and the Foreach ` ... | Where {$_.Length} | Foreach  { ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get something started. If you have an array of bytes you could pipe it into `Select-Object`

```
get-content -path $Path\*.* -encoding byte | Select-Object -Index (0..255)
```

That will get the first 256 bytes. Depending on the actual count of bytes you could easily loop through them in 256 chunks until you get to the end. `-Index` takes and `Int32` for parameter so this would not work for large files. `[int32]::MaxValue` = 2147483647

If you wanted the last 256 Characters you could do this.

```
$theBytes = get-content -path $Path\*.* -encoding byte
$theBytes | Select-Object -Index (($theBytes.Length - 256)..$theBytes.Length)
```

Or say you wanted everything but the last 256.

```
$theBytes | Select-Object -Index (0..($theBytes.Length - 256))
```

*Note* That arrays in PowerShell are base 0 by default. I dont think i did it wrong but check to be sure that the amount of bytes collected or ignored is the right amount. Also, this would error out if your files are smaller than 256 bytes.

Comment: Looking at your posts, I think I overcomplicated the logic. It is probably much simple, and I should not be using an array. I have several binary files and each of them has the trailer (the same by  the way), and I need to combine them into one file with only one trailer in the result file. I think I should be able to do it one liner????

Comment: Looks like it does not recognize Tail command: Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Tail'.